# Accidentally submitting comments by tapping the return button on iPad

Tags: discussion, questions, comments

On numerous occasions, I have posted an unfinished comment by accidentally pressing the return key on my iPad. (I personally think you should have to press the “Add Comment” button on the site to submit the comment, so that this can’t happen.)

I deleted each comment as soon as I accidentally posted them. Could the system detect this as abuse, and I get penalized for it? I don't try to do it, but sometimes I accidentally press the return button instead of another key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m not aware of any automated penalty, but I find I like to do editing of things that are needing thought in another app like drafts or notepad and then past it in here when I don’t have the full question / answer editor. Also - consider putting up a proper answer if your comment isn’t a short item that clarifies the comment.

I don’t know of any comments you’ve made that were flagged, but if the shoe fits - consider putting in an answer rather than a comment or crafting your comment and then pasting if you feel you are causing issues with the comments.

Comment: Thanks for this. I try not to put answers in comments, it’s usually when I am trying to reword a comment. I will probably use a text editor from now on.

Comment: @rydev awesome. Thanks for participating and adding careful comments. We appreciate that more than you might expect. I wanted to answer for some other people that are in the habit of floating answers in the comments